# is it possible to create a new stacking context WITHOUT the element being painted as if it's positioned?

Tags: html, css, dom, z-index, stacking-context

## what is the question?

Under the current spec of CSS, for any element, creating a new stacking context is equivalent to being painted as if it's positioned.

Various properties creating a new context like `opacity`, `isolation` and so on inevitably lead the browser to handle the element with the property as positioned.

For example, if you just add to an element only `opacity` less than 1 and no `position`, the browser will paint the element as positioned. **This means an element with `opacity` less than 1 and no `position` is always over any non-positioned elements.**

Any property creating a new stacking context like `isolation` are the same.

You can check this info from this discussion.
https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2717

So does anyone know any "hack" for creating a new stacking context WITHOUT the element being painted as if it's positioned?

## why am i asking it?

### background

I'm now developing a personal browser extension which adds popups, rect and so on to the web page the user is opening, through DOM scripting.

I don't wanna change anything about the original DOM including style, because I want the basic view of the web page to be kept as the original.

**All I can do is just add/insert some new DOMs without destroying the web page.**

### the main problem

In the development mentioned above, i wanna insert some elements with `position: relative` between two div elements: one is without any setting of `position` and the other is without any setting of `position` **but with `float` setting**.

Please run the below snippet. I wanna insert some positioned elements between them.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="cover">float: left and no-position</div>
    <div class="target">no-float and no-position</div>
  </body>
</html>

<style>
  .target {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
  }
  .cover {
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
  }
</style>
```

Of course, just inserting some elements with `position: relative` fails, because positioned elements are painted always over non-positioned elements.

Here, if i can create a new stacking context between them, the goal will be achieved.

However, again, under the current spec of CSS, for any element, creating a new stacking context is equivalent to being painted as if it's positioned. **That means newly created stacking contexts are always over the floated elements...**

So anyone has a solution?? Thank you for taking your precious time!

Comment: Hi @Kaiido, thank you for clarification.

I'm now developing a personal extension which adds popups, rect and so on to the web page the user is opening, through DOM scripting.

So here, I don't wanna change anything about the original DOM including style, because I want the basic view of the web page to be kept as the original.

All I can do is just add/insert some new DOMs without destroying the web page.

Please tell me if i can add more info:)

Comment: Many thanks @Kaiido, i edited it!!! looking forward to any help...!

Comment: what do you mean by --> *Here, if i can create a new stacking context between them, the goal will be achieved.* ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank you for clarification! I mean that if i can insert a new stacking context which is in the stacking order between the two divs, i will be able to insert elements between the two divs by putting the elements on the sandwiched context.